# Should I refer to the line numbers in the PDF generated by the submission system?

Tags: peer-review

When you refer to your revisions in your revision submission, should you refer to line numbers in your manuscript document or the line numbers in the PDF generated by the submission system?

Answer (score 2):

If reviewers used one particular system, stick with that. Otherwise use the ones that best match up to the actual lines in your manuscript (lots of editorial management systems add useless "line numbers" which don't correspond at all). If you think there'll be any confusion, just state at the top of your response which you're using.

Comment: Actually, there _will_ be confusion if the numbering is different. Probably use the reviewers numbering in a response, but also state that you are doing so.

Comment: Sadly, the reviewers did not use any.